# Thin-client Edubuntu 14.04 LTSP

Tags: edubuntu, ltsp, ltsp-client

I'm using VBox for this:

I already have 2 thin-client PC-1 and PC-2, and in the server I have 3 users: `staff`, `student`, `archie (admin)`

What I want to do with the client is, how to make both of them login using the same username and able to using same application at the same time is that possible?

I already tried PC-1 and PC-2 already able to login using staff username but when I open LibreOffice in PC-1, it just keep opening in PC-2 screen it can't open in both screens

Is it possible if in PC-1 I want to open `LibreOffice` Writer while in PC-2 I want to open `LibreOffice` Writer too or other app?